# Flask app config from YAML file is not loaded

Tags: python-3.x, flask, yaml

My app needs configs like = `app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'OU=users,dc=example,dc=org'` I want to pass this configurations to a YAML file and then make the app use it. I can load the file using `PyYAML` or `config_with_yaml` the problem is i can't set the app to use it as configurations.
It should work based on "https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/configuration.html"

I load my config with `cfg = config.load("/Users/pjose/Project/dev_maintenance/backend/config.yaml")` then i set my app config to get the data from the yaml file `app.config.from_object(cfg)` and by calling `app.config["LDAP_USERNAME"]` it should set the config, but it does not work.

YAML file:

```
LDAP_USERNAME: 'CN=Hermes Conrad,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com'
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/Users/pjose/Project/dev_maintenance/backend/dev_maintenance/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    app.config["LDAP_USERNAME"]
KeyError: 'LDAP_USERNAME'
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally could make this work

The problem was that i was not passing the value in the `YAML` file to the `app.config["LDAP_USERNAME"]` as there are no references of this subject on the documentation that i used and i though it would fetch the value just by declaring like that.

So a example on how you could use a `YAML` file to set you app configurations is:

config.yaml

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI: "sqlite://"
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS : False
```

Then to get the values you need to parse the yaml using the PyYAML lib or other:

```
data = yaml_loader.yaml("/Users/pjose/Project/dev_maintenance/backend/config.yaml")
app.config.from_object(data)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = data.setdefault('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
```